# Maps disapear on my WordPress website when using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my Word Press website I inserted an API key that I had issued in the Google API Manager. 
Now, the map is shown for a blink and than disappear with some kind of error.
Please see:
http://www.thecinemadoors.com/all-in-one-map/?h=801

Is the problem with the Wordpress theme or with my API Key?
Thanks,
Tamir

Answer (score 1):

I found following error:

Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error

ApiNotActivatedMapError     Error

The Google Maps JavaScript API is not activated on your API project. You may need to enable the Google Maps JavaScript API under APIs in the Google API Console.

See Obtaining an API key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key